# Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current position

Tags: sql, vba

I am trying to append parameters to insert to my sql table. Apparently I get the error message as "Applicaton uses a value of the wrong type for the current position" in the below code. I am not sure where I went wrong. Is it possible if I can round the final value ?

```
 If .Cells(2, counter) = "" Then LAWYERS_ATTORNEYS_AUDITED = 0 Else
Set param = objMyCmd.CreateParameter("@LAWYERS_ATTORNEYS_AUDITED", adNumeric, adParamInput)
     param.Precision = 18
     param.NumericScale = 2
     param.Value = .Cells(2, counter)
     objMyCmd.Parameters.Append param
counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27047076/How-to-set-NumericScale-and-Precision-with-adDecimal-when-calling-stored-procedure-in-VBA.html

Comment: What is the data type in the DB?

Comment: I am using numeric(18,2) in the create table part !